# Any open-source software that is similar to Fortify?

Tags: security, open-source, findbugs, pmd, fortify

I have been using PMD and Findbug for my application but fortify managed to detect some of the security vulnerabilities in my application. I am wondering if there is other open-source software that does the similar job as Fortify?

Answer (score 9):

If your focus is on security, you could benefit from additional security rules. [Find Security Bugs](http://h3xstream.github.io/find-sec-bugs/) is a set of detectors for FindBugs.

**Disclaimer** : I'm the author of the tool mention

Here is an exhaustive list of static analyzers maintained by the nist : http://samate.nist.gov/index.php/Source_Code_Security_Analyzers.html

Comment: Hey @h3xStream is it possible to use your plugin in build.xml?

Comment: I have not use it myself. But here is the doc: http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/manual/anttask.html

Answer (score 1):

[Sonar](http://www.sonarsource.com/products/features/) is pretty similar to Fortify. However, it focuses more on code quality/metrics rather than security. There is some overlap in informational. Additionally, there are plugins for Sonar such as [Security Rules](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Security+Rules+Plugin) that allow you to add more security metrics.